# Using custom token in node body

Tags: nodes, tokens

I am trying to minimize my workload in the future by putting recycled content into tokens, so that I only have to update the token as opposed to updating each individual node that uses the same content. I have little experience with tokens, so my question is very basic.

Example of what I want.. say I have the following on dozens of different nodes:

Item 1: $29.99

Rather than having to update each node when 'Item 1' gets a price change, I'd rather have each node just using a token for 'Item 1', so that I only have to update the token instead of all the nodes. I've installed the [Custom Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) module, but don't understand how to display my custom token in the node's content body. If I set the custom token name as "token-1", how would I display the token in the actual content? ie. [token-1], [custom:token-1] etc don't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to have the [Token filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module installed and configured in your text formats to use tokens in the node body.

Comment: I ran into this exact scenario, and detailed the whole solution using Custom Token [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164688/inserting-custom-html-using-tokens/166049)

Answer (score 2):

Try `token_replace` in `hook_nodeapi`  for D6 or `hook_node_load` for D7

[token_replace](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7)

> Parameters
>
> **$text**: A string potentially containing replaceable tokens.
>
> **$data:** (optional) An array of keyed objects. For simple replacement
>   scenarios 'node', 'user', and others are common keys, with an
>   accompanying node or user object being the value. Some token types,
>   like 'site', do not require any explicit information from $data and
>   can be replaced even if it is empty.
>
> **$options: (optional) A keyed array of settings and flags to control
>   the token replacement process. Supported options are:**
>
> language: A language object to be used when generating
>   locale-sensitive tokens. callback: A callback function that will be
>   used to post-process the array of token replacements after they are
>   generated. For example, a module using tokens in a text-only email
>   might provide a callback to strip HTML entities from token values
>   before they are inserted into the final text. clear: A boolean flag
>   indicating that tokens should be removed from the final text if no
>   replacement value can be generated. sanitize: A boolean flag
>   indicating that tokens should be sanitized for display to a web
>   browser. Defaults to TRUE. Developers who set this option to FALSE
>   assume responsibility for running filter_xss(), check_plain() or other
>   appropriate scrubbing functions before displaying data to users.

[hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

[hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)